# Need to continually re-install node modules after every angular library build

Tags: angular, npm, build, angular-library, npm-link

*I found it really hard to phrase this question. I hope it makes sense.
I have searched here and more generally to try to find a reference to this behaviour but haven't found anything.*

I have an angular library project which has been working perfectly for several months.

Wanting to add a new (slightly complex) new feature to the library I got tired of copying the built library to my main project after each test.

After some research, I discovered `npm link` which I hadn't used before. This worked brilliantly for about a week. After each change in the library project I rebuilt the library and the changes were immediately available in my main project.

Then just yesterday something really weird started happening. I went to build the library project and got pages or errors. (See below)

Reinstalling all the npm packages fixed the problem but when I went to used my main project, all the errors reappeared there.

Then I made some changes to the library project and went to rebuild and all the errors were back again.

Any ideas on what is happening here??

## 2020-06-30 Edit

As per one of my comments below, this was OK for a few days but I had to re-install yesterday and again this morning.

````
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3670:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3670     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<RangeValueAccessor>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3740:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3740     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<RequiredValidator>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3852:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3852     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<SelectControlValueAccessor>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3948:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3948     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:4380:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

4380     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_n>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:4440:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

4440     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ɵNgNoValidate>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:4479:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

4479     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ɵNgSelectMultipleOption>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

An unhandled exception occurred: node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:219:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

219     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ApplicationInitStatus>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:402:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

402     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ApplicationRef>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:748:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

748     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<Compiler>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5065:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

5065     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<PlatformRef>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6453:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

6453     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<SystemJsNgModuleLoader>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6650:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

6650     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<Testability>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6695:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

6695     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<TestabilityRegistry>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:9638:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

9638     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ɵConsole>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:100:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

100     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<AsyncPipe>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:201:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

201     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<CurrencyPipe>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:360:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

360     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<DatePipe>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:418:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

418     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<DecimalPipe>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:902:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

902     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<HashLocationStrategy>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:933:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

933     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<I18nPluralPipe>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:963:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

963     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<I18nSelectPipe>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1011:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1011     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<JsonPipe>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1066:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1066     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<KeyValuePipe>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1213:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1213     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<Location>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1268:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1268     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<LocationStrategy>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1291:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1291m     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<LowerCasePipe>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1355:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1355     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgClass>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1428:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1428     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgComponentOutlet>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1586:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1586     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgForOf<any, any>>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1785:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1785     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgIf<any>>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1810:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1810     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgLocaleLocalization>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1864:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1864     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgPlural>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1893:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1893     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgPluralCase>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:1946:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1946     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgStyle>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2027:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2027     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgSwitch>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2078:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2078     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgSwitchCase>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2100:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2100     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgSwitchDefault>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2157:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2157     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgTemplateOutlet>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2302:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2302     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<PathLocationStrategy>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2346:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2346     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<PercentPipe>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2388:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2388     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<PlatformLocation>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2484:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2484     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<SlicePipe>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2530:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2530     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<TitleCasePipe>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2565:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2565     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<UpperCasePipe>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:2672:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2672     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ɵBrowserPlatformLocation>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:2058:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2058     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<Router>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:2295:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2295     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<RouterLink>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:2388:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2388     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<RouterLinkActive>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:2480:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2480     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<RouterLinkWithHref>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:2618:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2618     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<RouterOutlet>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:2649:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2649     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<RouterPreloader>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:3044:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3044     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ɵangular_packages_router_router_h>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:3105:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3105     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ɵangular_packages_router_router_o>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:3120:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3120     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ɵEmptyOutletComponent>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:3121:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta' requires 7 type argument(s).

3121     static ɵcmp: ɵngcc0.ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta<ɵEmptyOutletComponent, "ng-component", never, {}, {}, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fourcast/base/lib/base.service.d.ts:4:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

4     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<BaseService>;
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fourcast/base/lib/base.component.d.ts:6:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

6     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<BaseComponent>;
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fourcast/base/lib/base.component.d.ts:7:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta' requires 7 type argument(s).

7     static ɵcmp: ɵngcc0.ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta<BaseComponent, "lib-base", never, {}, {}, never>;
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:678:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

678     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<AbstractControlDirective>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:749:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

749     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<AbstractFormGroupDirective>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:868:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

868     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<CheckboxControlValueAccessor>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:900:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

900     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<CheckboxRequiredValidator>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:935:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

935     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ControlContainer>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:1127:93m18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1127     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<DefaultValueAccessor>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:1175:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1175     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<EmailValidator>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:1602:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1602     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<FormArrayName>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:1686:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1686     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<FormBuilder>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:1966:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

1966     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<FormControlDirective>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:2082:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2082     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<FormControlName>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:2539:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2539     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<FormGroupDirective>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:2606:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2606     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<FormGroupName>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:2679:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2679     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<MaxLengthValidator>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:2736:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2736     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<MinLengthValidator>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:2858:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2858     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgControlStatus>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:2875:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

2875     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgControlStatusGroup>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3081:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3081     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgForm>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3277:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3277     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgModel>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3322:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3322     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgModelGroup>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3365:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3365     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NgSelectOption>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3437:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3437     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<NumberValueAccessor>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3494:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3494     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<PatternValidator>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3597:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3597     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<RadioControlValueAccessor>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3670:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3670     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<RangeValueAccessor>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3740:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3740     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<RequiredValidator>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3852:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3852     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<SelectControlValueAccessor>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3948:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

3948     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:4380:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

4380     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ɵangular_packages_forms_forms_n>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:4440:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

4440     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ɵNgNoValidate>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:4479:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).

4479     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ɵNgSelectMultipleOption>;```
````

Comment: Have tried deleting package-lock.json and reinstalling everything?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I tried that too. Delete package-lock. Delete node-modules. Run npm install. The build works after that. But then I go into the source, make a few edits and build again. All the errors come back.

Comment: When u say u have "made some changes", can you be more specific, what you did? Like have u installed any dependency?

Comment: I haven't installed anything. I just changed about two lines of code in the typescript. I think I added an If clause so maybe three lines altogether.

Comment: Ok. Try to do the same in ur library first. Delete node modules and install again. Then do same in ur application. This happened to me while back, and reinstalling everything in library worked. Pls try this.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts and fast response. I really appreciate some extra eyes on this. Regarding your latest comment, the problem occurs in my library. I delete everything there and rebuild. It works OK. Make some changes and try to rebuild I get the errors. It has to be something to do with npm-link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216613/discussion-between-chris-curnow-and-plochie).

Comment: I have no idea what was happening here but a few rounds through deleting node-modules and package-lock and it seems to be OK now??

Comment: I think its just a caching issue. Im not sure though.

Comment: I've made the same thing, but i haven't change any line, and appears that errors
1)I tried deletting the node_modules, and the package-lock and make a npm install
2) Tried with npm ci too
But there's no another answer, when every on these answer failed

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get past this if I set "enableIvy": false in tsconfig.lib.json in the source library. Not really a long term solution, but at least it's more information

> "angularCompilerOptions": {
> "enableIvy": false,   },